# iFrame with background colour in IE6

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

Is it possible to style an iframe with a background colour within MS IE6?

If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it programatically from the "parent" page with Javsacript like this...

```
window.frames["frameName"].document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

In order for this to work, however, the page within the frame has to sit on the same domain as the parent.

Comment: Hi Josh, tried it but all that seems to happen is that the iframe border changes to green and not the whole background.